# Javascript alert only initiating for top row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an alert set off every time a button is clicked on, which is a column in a table.

However, the alert is only working when the user clicks the button in the top row. All rows below it does not work. Why?!

```
<span class="inline" id="part-name" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;"> {{unipart.part}}</span>



    <td id ="Buy">
                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{offer.buynow_url}}">BUY NOW </a>
            </td>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Buy').click(function() {
   var myPart = $('#part-name').text();
   alert (myPart);
});
</script>
```

Note I have tried with `id="Buy"` in both the `td` tag, and also the `a` tag.

Comment: Show some code where it DOESN'T work.

Comment: Are all your cells or rows using the same ID? IDs must be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your structure. That being said, I'm going to venture a guess and assume that you've got a a set of repeat <span></span><td></td> elements all having IDs of #buy and #part-name. Putting aside the structure.. one very important rule: There can only ever be a single element with an unique ID per page. If you want to target multiple elements, that's where classes come in.

Comment: If all your tds have the same ID, it is not going to work. Use an unique ID (with is the definition of an ID) are class="Buy" instead. **Edit** j08691 was faster than I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to multiple DOM elements, bind to a class that they share instead (make a new class and use that class on each element).

Your DOM structure seems somewhat confusing, but if I understand it correctly, this should work.

```
<span class="inline" id="part-name" class="part-name" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;"> {{unipart.part}}</span>

<td class="buy" id ="Buy">
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{offer.buynow_url}}">BUY NOW </a>
        </td>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.buy').click(function() {
   var myPart = $(this).closest('tr').children('.part-name').text();
   alert (myPart);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working, but returning a blank for `closest()` ... if just have `$('.part-name').text();` it returns a list of all the part names if the column. Do you know why it might return a blank with `closest()`?

Comment: @user1328021 In this case, you probably don't want to use closest() on second thought.  I wasn't sure on your full DOM structure.  If $('.part-name').text() works correctly, then use that.

Comment: Well it returns every single item in the column... I just the want that corresponds to the same row.

Comment: @user1328021 I need to see more of your html to be certain how this is working.  Do you have multiple part-name spans?  Or do you have one per table row?  If both the span and the td have the same parent element, my latest update will work for you

Comment: @user1328021 You're more than welcome!  Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ID "Buy", give class name 'Buy' then use the below code

```
 $('.Buy').on('click',function(){
     alert($('#part-name').text());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're selecting the s by their ids.  Id's are supposed to be unique, so jQuery is grabbing the first one.  If you use classes it will work better.

```
<span class="inline" id="part-name" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;"> {{unipart.part}}</span>

<td class='Buy'>
  <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{offer.buynow_url}}">BUY NOW </a>
</td>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.Buy').click(function() {
  var myPart = $('#part-name').text();
  alert (myPart);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might want to do something like this:

```
   <span class="inline" id="part-name-{{partID}}" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;"> {{unipart.part}}</span>



    <td class ="Buy">
                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{offer.buynow_url}}" partId="{{partID}}">BUY NOW </a>
            </td>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.Buy').click(function() {
   var myPart = $("#part-name-"+$(this).attr("partId")).text();
   alert (myPart);
});
</script>
```

This will break validation unless you are using HTML5.